# Universal volume control for whole website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, html5-audio

my website has several audio players on one page. Mostly these audio players would depend on an html5 `<audio>` element, however for some sites there is an flash / `<object>` fallback. I was thinking to include volume controls for each player, but than thought That I can use one Universal volume control for all of them (as there can be only one player playing at a time) I tried researching this topic, but could not find any useful information. Therefore I decided to ask the community, is there a way to, no matter if it is `<audio>` or flash fallback, to control volume of the whole website? Maybe jQuery solution, some html5 magic? Or what needs to be done in order for this to work?

Players are based on this plugin: http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/docs/

EDIT: Something very similar to sound cloud, they have volume control in the header, which controls all players.

Comment: Do you have programmatic control over each type of player? I'm going to assume yes on the `<audio>` element, but what about the Flash player? Can you control it via JavaScript?

Comment: @Kai Sorry, for not stating that. Yes I do Have control over audio, Like play, pause rewind etc.. My player is based on the following plugin: http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/docs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to simplify your audio implementation I would suggest taking a look at [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) which abstracts away dealing with browsers that don't support HTML5 audio (and/or specific audio codecs). Its API works the same whether it's using native audio or the Flash fallback.

Then you would just have to create some global audio reference that would hold onto whatever audio you were currently playing:

```
var myAudio,
    myVolume = 100,
    $volume = $('#volume');

$volume.slider({
  value: myVolume,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  step: 0.1,
  slide: function(e, ui){
    if (myAudio) myAudio.setVolume(ui.value);
  },
  stop: function(e, ui){
    myVolume = ui.value;
  }
});

// every time you wan to play a new sound
myAudio = soundManager.createSound({
  url: '/path/to/song.mp3'
  volume: $volume.slider('value')
});
```

And every time the user clicks something to play another piece of audio, just assign the new sound object to `myAudio`.

Comment: Hi, Yes I heard about SoundManager, but decided to go for a different, more lightweight approach, I updated my answer to include plugin that I am using, to deal with all the audio, I'd really not want to use soundmanager.

Comment: FYI, SoundCloud uses SoundManager2 for its audio player. What you're looking for is outside the scope of what Audio.js offers (which is simply a polyfill for the HTML5 audio element).

Comment: Alright I see, was thinking that it is possible to somehow control volume of audio, as a general thing, oh well ;/